# UIAttachment not working in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, cgpoint, uidynamicbehavior

I have the following code which simply attaches a password `UITextField` to an `anchorPoint`. When I run this nothing happens.

```
UIDynamicItemBehavior *behavior = 
 [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[passwordTextField]];

CGPoint anchor = passwordTextField.center;
anchor.y -= 200;

_attachment = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:passwordTextField 
                                        attachedToAnchor:anchor];

_gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[passwordTextField]];
_gravity.magnitude = 10;

[behavior addChildBehavior:_gravity];
[behavior addChildBehavior:_attachment];

[_animator addBehavior:behavior];
```

Comment: What does it mean "nothing happens"? It compiles, does it not?
What do you think should happen?
How does the result behaviour differ from what you expected?

Comment: You don't explain what you really want to do, can you please add additional information?

Answer (score 1):

The attachment doesn't change the position of the item. Instead it only makes the distance between the item and the attachment point to be fixed.

If you wish to modify the distance then try UISnapBehavior.